# Edit User Information as Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am working on a project via Rails 4+ where I would like admin to be able to edit user information. At the moment, I have admin as a boolean within my user model (while using Devise). An admin account can currently delete a user from the site but I seem to be confused when it comes to editing user information.

I've been reading a bit online and I do not want to use cancan or another gem as I do not think it's really needed? Additionally I do not really have any code setup yet because I am really confused on how to go about making this happen. Not looking for a easy/quick answer, I am just lost to the point that I do not know where/how to begin.

If you have any idea how to accomplish this and/or any guides that could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not that hard to achieve. I am not using CanCan nor do I use Devise inside the code that I am about to show you, it is all made manually. However, I still think it might help you out...

Consider an example **users_controller.rb** file...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  .
  .
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  .
  .
  private
    .
    .
    # Confirms that user is correct.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?
    end
    
    # Confirms that a user is logged-in
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Below are several methods used in the above two..

    # Logs in the given user.
    def log_in(user)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end        

    # Returns true if the given user is the current user.
    def current_user?(user)
      user == current_user
    end

    # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
    def current_user
      if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
      elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
          log_in user
          @current_user = user
        end
      end
    end

    # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
    def logged_in?
      !current_user.nil?
    end
```

If you look closely at the top of the controller file, there you will find `before_action` which is a command which arranges for a particular method to be called before the given actions are allowed to happen.

So, inside the line `before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]` what I am asking Rails to do is to check if the user is correct before letting to update or edit users information.

And according to my definition of the `correct_user`...

```
def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?
end
```

... a correct user is **either** a user holding this account or the **admin**. Which as a result will not redirect me to the root page, but instead let me edit the user's in question page.

I hope this helps you out.

### **UPDATE:**

> When an admin edits a users information, they should not have to know the password to do so. Is this implemented in your code somehow or how would one bypass that?

First of all, I will not be able to see the password anyway actually because it is stored as a digest, **however** if you would not even want to let the admin even edit the password, then what you should do is the following...

inside your **edit.html.erb**, just place password fields inside an if statement...

```
<% if !current_user.admin? %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

<% end %>
```

...which does exactly this.

And if I would want to see proof that the user's info is secure, we can have a look at the console...

```
2.2.1 :001 > User.first
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Fake User", email: "fake@fakemail.org", created_at: "2015-07-11 18:36:00", updated_at: "2015-07-11 18:36:00", password_digest: "$2a$10$RpVWwRKWIQObTDow3PLGWOgjxqNNK.LU8p.fEPOVVnT...", remember_digest: nil, admin: nil, activation_digest: "$2a$10$jUZiRIiiBnpCSEv0h/KKi.fqdW3hVn94XFxxQS.n62X...", activated: true, activated_at: "2015-07-11 18:36:00", reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil>
```

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense and of course is easier than I was expecting. Just an additional question: When an admin edits a users information, they should not have to know the password to do so. Is this implemented in your code somehow or how would one bypass that?

Comment: Yes Joe, I will update my post briefly for you to see how to do that. Although, I will never ever will be able to see anyones password since it is stored as a hashed digest.

Comment: Thank you - Exactly. Without knowing the users password, additional code would need to be implemented. For users, I require them to place their current password to make changes. Obviously admin cannot have that same priority.

Comment: Of course! Jeez, how silly of me =P Perfect, your help has been priceless and I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped you out! All best

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check out active_admin, you can accomplish that pretty easily.

For rails 4, you just need to use the master branch.

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

For more info [see docs here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin)

Comment: I've heard of this gem before but as mentioned, I would prefer to not use a gem, unless it's really needed. To my knowledge, it's possible to do it without adding another gem? I am hesitant with having too many gems within one project.

Comment: If you want an admin section for the admin to edit user info then active admin is a good choice if you just want the admin to be able to edit users on user edit page then you don't need it, but as your application grows having a dedicated admin section would make thing easily manageable, you can add other objects to it as well and make them manageable

Comment: You are right and I've read that in many areas when doing my research. Right now though, I don't know if being that advanced will happen at all. If it does in the future, then I will revisit (which I know it is difficult to change later), but again, I don't want to jump ahead with this gem if that never ends up being needed. Thank you so much for your input =)